# How to separate JavaScript files in a Blazor project?

Tags: javascript, blazor

I have a big project with over 10 modules, each module has it's own javascript files, We only work on a single module at a time and I don't need whole the javascripts contents,So Should I load them all or how can I separate them for each module? 
It may be a solution to use a separated .cshtml file for each module to host the .razor components, Is this the clue?

Comment: hello, i don't know what "blazor" is about, but forgetting that, i'd say you should just use standard native es-modules to load whatever you want and nothing more — just use a `<script type="module" src="my-module.js"></script>` and that's all — cheers

Comment: thank you, but in blazor your code loads all the scripts files togather, I want to separate each components script files and load them when each component loads.

Comment: good luck, hopefully in the future you can move to a modern setup with a simple static frontend that you can completely control, and move to a more flexible microservices model

Comment: in a microservices model I can not share the static file folders(and layouts) and I should separate the ui layer. because each service is in a different web project.

Answer (score 0):

It would not be supported by Blazor itself during initial release on .NET Core 3.0
See https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore/issues/5465

**Variant 1**

If you want dynamically load JS files in parts, you have to assume that JS used by Blazor application, is not part of Blazor application itself, but rather some external environment which can some load each JS module. Blazor component has to manually load JS modules themselves.

```js
// Include that file in the index.html, but not inside Razor Components Project.
function loadModule(moduleName) {
   // load module somehow, via Ajax probably.
   // This function likely has to make sure that module would not be loaded twice.
}
```

```cs
protected override Task OnInitializedAsync() {
   // Component load JS module.
   await jsRuntime.InvokeVoidAsync("loadModule", "component1");
}
```

Again, JS files `component1.js` should be managed outside Blazor projects.

**Version 2**

Use `Assembly.Load` to load assembly with components and manually inject component in the UI somehow. Reflection is your friend here.

```
// Component1 assumed to be present in the `dist/_framework/_bin` folder where all Blazor stuff is located.
var assembly = Assembly.Load("Component1");
foreach (var type in assembly.GetTypes())
{
    if (!type.FullName.EndsWith("ModuleLoader"))
        return;

    var moduleInstance = Activator.CreateInstance(type);
    // And now all regular .NET plugin stuff.
}
```

Comment: thank you, but I want to load a group of JavaScript files related to a component at the component load event. I don't  want to load all the scripts and call them as a function. I wan to load the required functions and call them when they are needed.

Comment: Then my first statement, that this is not supported with latest link from ASP.NET Core repo which I can found. If you manage to load the `Assembly` then all Blazor magic will work. So in a sense, I think that this way will suit you better. Important note is that components should not be referenced from main application, that way they will not be loaded initially, and they should be loaded automatically.

Comment: you can suggest this to the dev team.

Comment: Im in the exact same boat.. js file on page 1 throws error because its expecting page 2.. smh.. if i come up with some hack I will report back